# CUPS/IPP over HTTPS via CF/Gorouter - TLS handshake error

Tags: cloud-foundry, tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception, cups, gorouter

I want to print PostScripts via CUPS/HTTPS on Cloud Foundry.
It's working when I'm using HTTP but fails for HTTPS with gorouter's log:

```
http: TLS handshake error from ...
```

My `cipher_suites`:

> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

I tried to set `router.logging_level` to `debug` ([default](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/routing-release/blob/661c5bc41d32f62d52ffe84dc206172e6938403b/jobs/gorouter/spec#L113) is `info`) but it changes nothing...

Is there any chance to get more information?
What is the most detailed log level for gorouter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
In my case mutual TLS was enabled on gourouter:

> By default, Gorouter requests but does not require client certificates in TLS handshakes.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/securing-traffic.html#gorouter_mutual_auth

---

## Checking if mTLS is enabled

### 1. Widows SCHANNEL event logging

Add a registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL
EventLogging REG_DWORD = 3
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kevinjustin/2017/11/08/schannel-event-logging/

Now you should find event logs that server asks for client certificate but it can't be found.

### 2. `curl`

Look at the bold lines:

```
curl -I -v -H "Connection: close" https://your-app.cloud
```

> - About to connect() to your-app.cloud port 443 (#0)
> - Connected to your-app.cloud port 443 (#0)
> - Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
> - CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none
> - **NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)**
> - SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

### 3. `openssl`

Look at the bold lines:

```
openssl s_client -connect your-app.cloud:443 -state
```

> - CONNECTED(00000003)
> - SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
> - SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
> - SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
> - ...
> - verify return:1
> - SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
> - SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server key exchange A
> - **SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A**
> - SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
> - **SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A**
> - SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
> - SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
> - SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
> - SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
> - SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server session ticket A
> - SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A

---

## Disable Gorouter mTLS

Change Gorouter properties using CF deployment manifest:

```
- name: router
  - name: gorouter
    release: routing
    properties:
      router:
        forwarded_client_cert: always_forward
        client_cert_validation: none
```

Now you can check if mTLS is enabled again.

*Note that these settings didn't for the routing version `0.164.0` but for `0.178.0` it works as expected.*